# How can I recieve/send multiple messages at the same time in python? (Python Multithreading)

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets

I have followed some instructions to make a chat app in python using socket, and it is working fine. However, due to the way it is written, you can only send messages when a message has been sent first. Basically, you can't send multiple messages at the same time. However, I would really like to incorporate this. The person who made the tutorial said that this could be achieved through multi-threading, but didn't elaborate further. Can someone explain what they mean? Thanks. Here is the sever side code:

```
import socket
import sys
import time

s = socket.socket()
host = socket.gethostname()
port = 8080
s.bind((host,port))
print("\n")
print(host)
print("\n")
name = input("Please enter your username: ")
s.listen(1)
print("\n")
print("Waiting for incoming connections")
print("\n")
conn, addr = s.accept()
print("Connected")

s_name = conn.recv(1024)
s_name = s_name.decode()
print("\n")
print(s_name, " has connected to the server")
print("\n")
conn.send(name.encode())

while 1:
    message = input(">> ")
    conn.send(message.encode())
    message = conn.recv(1024)
    message = message.decode()
    print(message)
```

And the client side code:

```
import socket
import sys
import time

s = socket.socket()
print("\n")
host = input(str("Please enter host name: "))
print("\n")
name = input("Please enter your username: ")
port = 8080
print("\n")
print("Connecting to ", host, "at port", port)
print("\n")
s.connect((host,port))
print("Connected")

s.send(name.encode())
s_name = s.recv(1024)
s_name = s_name.decode()
print("\n")
print(s_name, " has joined the chat")

while 1:
    message = s.recv(1024)
    message = message.decode()
    print(message)
    message = input(">> ")
    s.send(message.encode())
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

if I understood well your problem the basic solution is that you have to create a while loop in which you accept connections and then handle them in a separate function-thread (serverside):

```
while True:
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    threading.Thread(target=connectionhandler, args=(conn,)).start()

def connectionhandler(conn):
    #do things with the connection
```

let me know if this is a possible solution for you